# Internal методы интерфейсов в C# - как это работает?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

У меня вопрос по поводу этого кода:

```cs
internal interface IRepository {
  internal void LoadFromDB();
  internal void SaveToDB();
}
```

Компилятор все принял, но когда я реализовываю интерфейс в классе, компилятор требует, чтобы эти методы были строго public.
В чем прикол? Зачем тогда разрешать делать их internal?

И даже если сам класс объявить как internal - всеравно требует public!

Собственно задача:
Реализовать интерфейс в кругу одной сборки, о котором (и его методах) никто ничего не знает (снаружи этой сборки)

Comment: В классе публичные, но в интерфейсе - internal. Ты можешь возвращать не класс, а интерфейс

Comment: Но я как раз таки работаю с классом. Получается интерфейс мне попросту не нужен

Comment: Надо смотреть что именно ты делаешь какая задача у тебя на самом деле стоит

Comment: Задача была спрятать эти методы, но при этом привязать к интерфейсу. Можно конечно приводить к интерфейсу явно, но это както замыливает код и не понятно почему оно не работает, если компилятор позволяет так писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуй explicitly наименования в классе:

```
internal interface IRepository
{
    internal void LoadFromDB();
    internal void SaveToDB();
}
```

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    void IRepository.LoadFromDB()
    {
    }

    void IRepository.SaveToDB()
    {
    }
}
```

Теперь методы в классе не будут доступны в других сборках, как и сам интерфейс, но сам класс будет доступен. Так же ты можешь просто сам класс указать как `internal` и сделать методы `public`

Comment: Да, действительно, если указывать явно интерфейс, то так работает. Просто я смотрел кучу обучающих материалов, даже на самом MSDN - они часто реализуют эти методы без явного указания (явно указывают когда коллизия имен методов двух интерфейсов с разной реализацией)

В общем, спасибо, но так и не ясно почему оно не работает по-человечески

Comment: @Artem оно норм работает. Методы в классе ЯВНО реализуют (обращаясь по имени интерфейса к конкретному методу). Почитай [почему так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598714/implicit-vs-explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: Это то понятно, но я же не расширяю доступ, а оставляю как есть. Зато оно по умолчанию доступ расширяет, заставляя меня делать internal методы public. Тут я логику не понимаю